# How to create a magento payment module with api integration

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I searching for a module that can do API in Moneris payment gateway. I really need it, can anyone help me on how to start on this module? 
or any tutorial that can help how to do it. i already have done magentocommerce steps on how to create a payment module but still dont fit my need and requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google results:

- [Create Payment Method Module - Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module)
- [How to create Magento payment module - Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)

Comment: +1. I  can vouch for both of these excellent tutorials. I used them as a basis of creating a Con-Way payment module on Magento 1.6.0.